# Adding rows to an html table using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to take some data from my javascript file and put it into new rows and columns in my html file. I think the problem might have to do with my script closing before the table in my html file. I currently have a table in my html file that looks like this:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 700px; height: 700px"></div>
            <script src="js/mapping.js"></script>


            <div id="tablebody">
            <p>
                <b>List of Nearby Locations</b>
            </p>
                <table class="table table-stripped">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Address</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>John Smith</td>
                            <td>1500 Pennsylvania Ave</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

and JS code that looks like this:

```
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.nearbySearch(request, callback);


    function callback(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                createMarker(results[i]);
                alert("name: " + results[i].name + ", Address:" + results[i].vicinity);
                $('#tablebody tr:last').after('<tr>"Name: " + results[i].name + ", Address: " + results[i].vicinity</tr>');
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing table cells in the table row, and I assume that you want to concatenate the name and vicinity into the code, not just showing Javascript code in the table:

```
$('#tablebody tr:last').after('<tr><td>Name: ' + results[i].name + ', Address: ' + results[i].vicinity + '</td></tr>');
```

Or perhaps with two cells in the row:

```
$('#tablebody tr:last').after('<tr><td>' + results[i].name + '</td><td>' + results[i].vicinity + '</td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for javascript based :

```
  tableObject.insertRow(index)
```

Or jQuery

```
 $('#tablebody').append('<tr>"Name: " + results[i].name + ", Address: " + results[i].vicinity</tr>');
```

Comment: make a fiddle real quick, and will get it working for you. Not with the API stuff, just the table code, and drop the google info. It is a jquery selector/tag issue.